# Using OverwriteList with TypeModel (not with attributes) - protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a class to which I cannot add attributes, so I am configuring the TypeModel instead. Is there a way to specify the OverwriteList behaviour on a property by configuring the TypeModel? Something like this maybe:

```
var property = model[typeof(Foo)].Add(1, "SomeList");
property.OverwriteList = true;
```

Comment: Not at a PC - but: try AddField instead of Add

Comment: That worked, thanks! AddField returns the ValueMember instead of the MetaType.